# Db4o is extremely slow in Eclipse debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, db4o

I'm working with a db4o database and have a database of approximately 1000-5000 objects on Mac OS X, developing in Eclipse Helios.

Currently, I'm retrieving all objects of a certain class:

```
ObjectSet<Task> query = m_container.query(Task.class);
```

But then, when I need to put it into a real ArrayList, it is awfully slow.
Funnily enough, that only is in Debug mode in Eclipse - it never finished (in approx. 5 min running at 100% CPU), hanging at the toArray method in the Constructor of ArrayList.

When I run it in normal mode, the same operation completes in a matter of seconds.

Has anyone of you experienced this or knows how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set or just the debug mode?

Comment: You are right! There are some breakpoint set, but not hit. You clued me in however: If I disable them, the whole program runs smoothly now, even in debug mode!

Comment: Conditional breakpoints or just plain ones?

Comment: Plain ones. They are nowhere near the db4o code, however. But strangely, disabling / cleaning them worked now like a charm. You want to add it as an answer, then I can close it?

Comment: also make sure your -Xmx setting is high enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at the breakpoints. These are the things that make the JVM work slower in the debug mode.

Comment: This did work. I have no clue exactly to why, but cleaning / disabling the breakpoints did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz, you saved my such a huge amount of time!